# C++ own exception practices

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception

I'm new to C++ exceptions and not quite sure how I should use them. I'm open to every exception handling practice, this are just some of my ideas.

I've recently rewritten my C libraries for some custom hardware which uses POSIX API for accessing GPIOs, I2C, UART and network sockets. 
Now I'm trying to find an exception design for the library of my custom hardware and interfaces mentioned above.

Current design:

- Own exceptions for every interface, e.g. `CustomHwException`, `GpioException`, `I2cException`, ...
- Embed additional information to every Exception (some common base class)

  - "Port" number, which can be used for logging and exception handling itself (while "Port" can be any number like an interface number, a real port number, pin number, etc.): `gpio12`, `i2c0`, `ttys0`, `port 32000`
  - Error message (string) for logging
  - Fatal / Non Fatal
  - Possible fix for the problem: E.g. None, Try again later, Reset interface, ...

What I've read about exceptions so far is that they should make our lives easier and I don't think errnos embedded in exceptions would add some real value.
The user gets an errno and has to decide what's best for him to do in this exceptional situation. Isn't it better that the library developer who knows the hardware and common problems with it decides what the user should do in case of an error (fix)?

I'm also not sure if it's a good idea to have an Exception for every interface. Is it better to catch exceptions of the low level interfaces in a (higher level) library and throw a higher level exception like `CustomHwException`? Wouldn't this lead to a mixture of code and error handling in the library?

How would you implement this?

Comment: Fatal/non fatal and possible fix should not be part of the exception, IMO. Typically, party that handles the exception knows the context and only it can decide whether something is fatal or not, or how to fix the issue. E.g. 'file not found' can be fatal if it is a main config file, or not if it is e.g. user preferences.

Comment: Make sure you document what exceptions can come from a function, and have a base exception so you can use it to avoid having unhandled exceptions (high level functions can catch the base exception type).

Comment: "the library developer who knows the hardware and common problems" That's not true for most real projects. It might be the case for an implementation of the standard library, but a generic open source library might have no idea whether it is running on a PC, an Android device or an Xbox. In that case, the client knows better what hardware it is developping for, and might be better at handling errors.

Comment: My example might be very specific, but I still don't think that the library user always knows how to handle an error of some low level interface like I2C. What would you recommend instead? Using a std exception like std::system_error and let the user decide how to handle exceptions?

Comment: You need to document which exceptions are thrown under which circumstances. IMO, info about possible fixes belongs to documentation, not to the exception, the same way as C functions return error codes and not information on how to fix problems. Client code can't use this info to do anything buy itself, so it is indeed documentation.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I think I assumed that exceptions should be "something more" that return error codes. To which degree should we add error information to exceptions? File not found can have several reasons: E.g. there's really no such file or it is busy. If there's no file I can't handle the error (if I really need that file), if it's busy I can try again later.

Comment: Hard to tell :) In c++ code, I prefer to add minimum info about the cause of the error, and put rest into documentation, while in C# I tend to write more detailed messages. In this example, 'file busy' should probably be modeled with some kind of access_denied exception and not file_not_found. I don't always get it right initially and have to shuffle it later, so i won't pretend to have all the answers :)

Comment: Alright, I'll try to find the right mix of error information and documentation. Thank you for your help

Comment: Make your catch as generic as possible. Fewer catch terms, faster execution. As for exception kinds, the rule of the thumb is: will the catcher code do differently for my new throw point than for a given exception? If not, always use the old exception, even if something else happened, and populate fields to describe the error. For example, if the program has to stop, throw sg. like FatalException. Tell the user in the what() message whether you could not open a config file, or you had no system resources, etc.